# Paging in a Rest Collection

Tags: http, rest, http-headers, pagination

I'm interested in exposing a direct REST interface to collections of JSON documents (think [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) or [Persevere](http://persvr.org/)). The problem I'm running into is how to handle the `GET` operation on the collection root if the collection is large.

As an example pretend I'm exposing StackOverflow's `Questions` table where each row is exposed as a document (not that there necessarily is such a table, just a concrete example of a sizable collection of 'documents'). The collection would be made available at `/db/questions` with the usual CRUD api `GET /db/questions/XXX`, `PUT /db/questions/XXX`, `POST /db/questions` is in play. The standard way to get the entire collection is to `GET /db/questions` but if that naively dumps each row as a JSON object, you'll get a rather sizeable download and a lot of work on the part of the server.

The solution is, of course, paging. Dojo has solved this problem in its [JsonRestStore](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/data/JsonRestStore#id7) via a clever RFC2616-compliant extension of using the `Range` header with a custom range unit `items`. The result is a `206 Partial Content` that returns only the requested range. The advantage of this approach over a query parameter is that it leaves the query string for...queries (e.g. `GET /db/questions/?score>200` or somesuch, and yes that'd be encoded `%3E`).

This approach completely covers the behavior I want. The problem is that [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) specifies that on a 206 response (emphasis mine):

> The **request** MUST have included a Range header field ([section 14.35](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.35))
> indicating the desired range, and MAY have included an If-Range
> header field ([section 14.27](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.27)) to make the request conditional.

This makes sense in the context of the standard usage of the header but is a problem because I'd like the 206 response to be the default to handle naive clients/random people exploring.

I've gone over the RFC in detail looking for a solution but have been unhappy with my solutions and am interested in SO's take on the problem.

Ideas I've had:

- *Return `200` with a `Content-Range` header!* - I don't think that this is wrong, but I'd prefer if a more obvious indicator that the response is only Partial Content.
- *Return `400 Range Required`* - There is not a special 400 response code for required headers, so the default error has to be used and read by hand. This also makes exploration via web browser (or some other client like Resty) more difficult.
- *Use a query parameter* - The standard approach, but I'm hoping to allow queries a la Persevere and this cuts into the query namespace.
- *Just return `206`!* - I think most clients wouldn't freak out, but I'd rather not go against a MUST in the RFC
- *Extend the spec! Return `266 Partial Content`* - Behaves exactly like 206 but is in response to a request that MUST NOT contain the `Range` header. I figure that 266 is high enough that I shouldn't run into collision issues and it makes sense to me but I'm not clear on whether this is considered taboo or not.

I'd think this is a fairly common problem and I'd like to see this done in a sort of de facto fashion so I or someone else isn't reinventing the wheel.

What's the best way to expose a full collection via HTTP when the collection is large?

Comment: Wow, that is a good example of a question where some serious thinking has been done before.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pagination in a REST web application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776448/pagination-in-a-rest-web-application)

Comment: As far as Dojo's approach in using the Range header, although Accept-Ranges allows for extension, from all I can tell, the EBNF for Range does not: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-14.35.2 . The spec indicates `Range = "Range" ":" ranges-specifier` where the latter in http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-14.35.1 is described merely as "byte-ranges-specifier" which must begin with "bytes-unit" which is defined as the string "bytes".

Comment: The `Content-Range` header applies to the body (can be used with request when uploading large files etc, or for response when downloading). The `Range` header is used to request a certain range. One should respond with `206` when the `Range` header was included in the request. If it was not, the response may still include a `Content-Range` header, but the response code should be `200`. This header actually seems ideal for paging.

Comment: But the RFC 2616 itself says that "HTTP/1.1
   implementations MAY ignore ranges specified using other units." So is it a good practice to use Range headers for pagination? coz it might compromise interoperability.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

My gut feeling is that the HTTP range extensions aren't designed for your use case, and thus you shouldn't try. A partial response implies `206`, and `206` must only be sent if the client asked for it.

You may want to consider a different approach, such as the one use in Atom (where the representation by design may be partial, and is returned with a status `200`, and potentially paging links). See [RFC 4287](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4287.txt) and [RFC 5005](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5005.txt).

Comment: The Dojo usage is completely within spec. If the server doesn't understand the `items` range unit, it returns a full response.

I'm familiar with Atom but that's not the general solution to Rest paging. This isn't a solution for a single case, more of what the general solution should be. Not all documents/collections fit the Atom model and there's no reason to force it unless required.

Comment: @KarlGuertin Agreed. Too bad this is the accepted answer, because it seems many in the community are actually embracing `Range` and `Content-Range` for paging purposes.

Answer (score 33):

I don't really agree with some of you guys. I've been working for weeks on this features for my REST service. What I ended up doing is really simple. My solution only makes a sense for what REST people call a collection.

Client MUST include a "Range" header to indicate which part of the collection he needs, or otherwise be ready to handle a 413 REQUESTED ENTITY TOO LARGE error when the requested collection is too large to be retrieved in a single round-trip.

Server sends a 206 PARTIAL CONTENT response, with the Content-Range header specifying which part of the resource has been sent, and an ETag header to identify the current version of the collection. I usually use a Facebook-like ETag {last_modification_timestamp}-{resource_id}, and I consider that the ETag of a collection is that of the most recently modified resource it contains.

To request a specific part of a collection, the client MUST use the "Range" header, and fill the "If-Match" header with the ETag of the collection obtained from previously performed requests to acquire other parts of the same collection. The server can therefore verify that the collection hasn't changed before sending the requested portion. If a more recent version exists, a 412 PRECONDITION FAILED response is returned to invite the client to retrieve the collection from scratch. This is necessary because it could mean that some resources might have been added or removed before or after the currently requested part.

I use ETag/If-Match in tandem with Last-Modified/If-Unmodified-Since to optimize cache. Browsers and proxies might rely on one or both of them for their caching algorithms.

I think that a URL should be clean unless it's to include a search/filter query. If you think about it, a search is nothing more than a partial view of a collection. Instead of the cars/search?q=BMW type of URLs, we should see more cars?manufacturer=BMW.

Comment: Did you mean 416 "Requested Range Not Satisfiable" or "413" Request Entity Too Large?

Comment: @Mohamed I think you mean `If-Unmodified-Since`, which corresponds to the E-Tag variant `If-Match`, rather than `If-Modified-Since`. That said, you might also consider removing this constraint, depending on your use case. Say you have a collection that only grows from the top (like some "newest first" style collection), the worst that can happen if that collection changes in-between requests is that a user who pages through a collection sees entries twice. (Which in itself is also a useful information: It tells the user the collection has changed)

Comment: 413 is "Request Entity Too Large", not "Requested Entity Too Large". It means the size of your request, for example when uploading a file, is larger than the server is willing to process. So using it for this doesn't seem to be completely appropriate.

Comment: @Mohamed I know it's an old question but if the ETag of a collection is the ETag of the most recently modified resource the collection contains, which value of the If-Match header should be used when modifying one resource in the collection? Using the value of the ETag returned with the collection is wrong since the client would be able to modify the resource even he doesn't see the last state of the resource.

Comment: @MickaelMarrache Each resource contained in a collection is projected with its own ETag in the response.

Comment: You say "search is nothing more than a partial view of a collection". The same applies for a page. And fetching a page is "filtering" as well. There's nothing wrong with page parameters in URLs as long as the relation between the page resources and the collection resource is clear. See e.g. https://www.w3.org/community/hydra/wiki/Collection_Design#Pagination

Comment: I strongly disagree about using `413`. This is an error code meaning that the client is *sending* something which the server refuses to accept due to size. Not the other way around! See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.11 (note that it says **request** payload. Not **response** payload)!

Comment: @neo Interesting aspect. It's the same idea as JulianReschke point out with https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5005#section-3 In conjunction with HAL https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-kelly-json-hal/ an interesting solution

Comment: @exhuma what alternative would you recommend? 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable seems good, except the client didn't ask for a range so it might be unexpected. 507 Insufficient Storage is another option but it would probably require a human-readable error message to indicate why you're rejecting the request. I don't see a good, fully-automatic, standards-compliant way to tell the client that it is required to use range headers.

Comment: @ngreen `507` is part of the WebDAV standard and signifies that the server does not have enough space to store the resource sent by the client. So the semantics are very different. And `416` is specific to `Range` requests which are troublesome mainly because ranges are only defined for bytes and a proxy is allowed to drop those headers. I currently don't see a standard way other than [the current top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/924714/160665). This needs a larger discussion which does not fit in SO comments. Maybe on https://chat.stackoverflow.com?

Answer (score 8):

You can still return `Accept-Ranges` and `Content-Ranges` with a `200` response code.  These two response headers give you enough information to *infer* the same information that a `206` response code provides explicitly.

I would use `Range` for pagination, and have it simply return a `200` for a plain `GET`.

This feels 100% RESTful **and** doesn't make browsing any more difficult.

Edit:
I wrote a blog post about this: http://otac0n.com/blog/2012/11/21/range-header-i-choose-you.html

Comment: how do you communicate the next part with this approach. If the pagination params are part of the query, it is easy to tell the consumer meta information like next page and last page.  like seen here https://docs.github.com/en/rest/guides/getting-started-with-the-rest-api#pagination

Answer (score 5):

If there is more than one page of responses, and you don't want to offer the whole collection at once, does that mean there are multiple choices?

On a request to `/db/questions`, return `300 Multiple Choices` with `Link` headers that specify how to get to each page as well as a JSON object or HTML page with a list of URLs.

```
Link: <>; rel="http://paged.collection.example/relation/paged"
Link: <>; rel="http://paged.collection.example/relation/paged"
...
```

You'd have one `Link` header for each page of results (an empty string means the current URL, and the URL is the same for each page, just accessed with different ranges), and the relationship is defined as [a custom one per the upcoming `Link` spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-nottingham-http-link-header-05#section-4.2).  This relationship would explain your custom `266`, or your violation of `206`.  These headers are your machine-readable version, since all of your examples require an understanding client anyway.

(If you stick with the "range" route, I believe your own `2xx` return code, as you described it, would be the best behavior here.  You're expected to do this for your applications and such ["HTTP status codes are extensible."], and you have good reasons.)

`300 Multiple Choices` says you SHOULD also provide a body with a way for the user agent to pick.  If your client is understanding, it should use the `Link` headers.  If it's a user manually browsing, perhaps an HTML page with links to a special "paged" root resource that can handle rendering that particular page based on the URL?  `/humanpage/1/db/questions` or something hideous like that?

---

The comments on Richard Levasseur's post remind me of an additional option: the `Accept` header (section 14.1).  Back when the oEmbed spec came out, I wondered why it hadn't been done entirely using HTTP, and wrote up an alternative using them.

Keep the `300 Multiple Choices`,  the `Link` headers and the HTML page for an initial naive HTTP `GET`, but rather than use ranges, have your new paging relationship define the use of the `Accept` header.  Your subsequent HTTP request might look like this:

```
GET /db/questions HTTP/1.1
Host: paged.collection.example
Accept: application/json;PagingSpec=1.0;page=1
```

The `Accept` header allows you to define an acceptable content type (your JSON return), plus extensible parameters for that type (your page number).  Riffing on my notes from my oEmbed writeup (can't link to it here, I'll list it in my profile), you could be very explicit and provide a spec/relation version here in case you need to redefine what the `page` parameter means in the future.

Comment: +1 link headers, but I'd also recommend the common first, prev, next, last rels, as well as RFC5005's prev-archive, next-archive, and current.

Comment: > *On a request to /db/questions, return 300 Multiple Choices with Link headers that specify how to get to each page [..]*  The problem with that (and with most pure REST designs) is that it's killing for latency. The goal is to minimize network requests. That first request should yield results, not links to more requests that eventually will give the data we need.

Comment: you can also check the sample which was created by Google for Android https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/main/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/api/ApiResponse.kt


**Check ApiSuccessResponse class**

Answer (score 4):

Edit:

After thinking about it a bit more, I'm inclined to agree that Range headers aren't appropriate for pagination.  The logic being, the Range header is intended for the server's response, not the applications.  If you served 100 megabytes of results, but the server (or client) could only process 1 megabyte at a time, well, thats what the Range header is for.

I'm also of the opinion that a subset of resources is its own resource (similar to relational algebra.), so it deserve representation in the URL.

So basically, I recant my original answer (below) about using a header.

---

I think you answered your own question, more or less - return 200 or 206 with content-range and optionally use a query parameter.  I would sniff the user agent and content type and, depending on those, check for a query parameter.  Otherwise, require the range headers.

You essentially have conflicting goals - let people use their browser to explore (which doesn't easily allow custom headers), or force people to use a special client that can set headers (which doesn't let them explore).

You could just provide them with the special client depending on the request - if it looks like a plain browser, send down a small ajax app that renders the page and sets the necessary headers.

Of course, there is also the debate about whether the URL should contain all the necessary state for this sort of thing.  Specifying the range using headers can be considered "un-restful" by some.

As an aside, it would be nice if servers could respond with a "Can-Specify: Header1, header2" header, and web browsers would present a UI so users could fill in values, if they desired.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've thought about the topic, but was hoping to get a second opinion. Happen to have a pointer for the header arguments?

Comment: Here's the only one i have bookmarked (see the discussion in the comments): http://barelyenough.org/blog/2008/05/versioning-rest-web-services/

Another site revolved around Ruby's usage of .json, .xml, .whatever in determining the content type of a request.  Some of the examples:
* language - putting it in the URL means sending the link to another country would render it in the wrong language.

* pagination - Putting it in the header means you can't link people to what you see

Comment: * content-type: a combination of language and pagination problems - if its in the url, what if the client doesn't support that content type (eg, a .ajax and a .html extension)?  Conversely, without that content-type in the url, you can't ensure the same representation is given.  "new ajax site! example.com/cool.ajax" vs "cool article here: example.com/article.ajax#id=123".

Comment: IMO, whether it goes in the URL or not depends on what it is.  My general rule is, if it would identify a concrete resource (be it a resource in a specific state, selection of resources, or discrete result), it goes in the URL.  Search queries, pagination, and restful transactions are good examples of this.  If its something that is needed to transform the abstract representation to a concrete representation, it goes in the header.  auth info and content-type are good examples of this.

Comment: I think of the query string in a URL as options for querying the resource being specified.

Answer (score 3):

You might consider using a model something like the Atom Feed Protocol since it has a sane HTTP model of collections and how to manipulate them (where insane means WebDAV).

There's the [Atom Publishing Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5023) which defines the collection model and REST operations plus you can use [RFC 5005 - Feed Paging and Archiving](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5005) to page through big collections.

Switching from Atom XML to JSON content should not affect the idea.

Answer (score 3):

I think the real problem here is that there is nothing in the spec that tells us how to do automatic redirects when faced with 413 - Requested Entity Too Large.

I was struggling with this same problem recently and I looked for inspiration in the *RESTful Web Services* book. Personally I don't think 206 is appropriate due to the header requirement.    My thoughts also led me to 300, but I thought that was more for different mime-types, so I looked up what Richardson and Ruby had to say on the subject in Appendix B, page 377.  They suggest that the server just pick the preferred representation and send it back with a 200, basically ignoring the notion that it should be a 300.

That also jibes with the notion of links to next resources that we have from atom.  The solution I implemented was to add "next" and "previous" keys to the json map I was sending back and be done with it.

Later on I started thinking maybe the thing to do is send a 307 - Temporary Redirect to a link that would be something like /db/questions/1,25 - that leaves the original URI as the canonical resource name, but it gets you to an appropriately named subordinate resource.  This is behavior I'd like to see out of a 413, but 307 seems a good compromise.  Haven't actually tried this in code yet though.  What would be even better is for the redirect to redirect to a URL containing the actual IDs of the most recently asked questions.  For example if each question has an integer ID, and there are 100 questions in the system and you want to show the ten most recent, requests to /db/questions should be 307'd to /db/questions/100,91

This is a very good question, thanks for asking it.  You confirmed for me that I'm not nuts for having spent days thinking about it.

Comment: 303 would be better in this regard than 307. 307 implies that the original URL will soon start responding as the client expects.

Comment: [RFC 7231](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.11) references HTTP status code 413 as _Payload Too Large_ and relates this code with request size and not potential response size.

Answer (score 2):

With the publication of [rfc723x](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/#rfc723x), **unregistered range units do go against an explicit recommendation in the spec**. Consider [rfc7233](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233) (deprecating rfc2616):

"[New range units ought to be registered with IANA](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233#section-2.2)"  (along with a reference to a [HTTP Range Unit Registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-parameters/http-parameters.xhtml#range-units)).

Answer (score 2):

One of the big problems with range headers is that a lot of corporate proxies filter them out.  I'd advise to use a query parameter instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can detect the `Range` header, and mimic Dojo if it is present, and mimic Atom if it is not. It seems to me that this neatly divides the use cases. If you are responding to a REST query from your application, you expect it to be formatted with a `Range` header. If you are responding to a casual browser, then if you return paging links it will let the tool provide an easy way to explore the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that the best way to do this is to include range as query parameters.  e.g., **GET /db/questions/?date>mindate&date<maxdate**.  Upon a GET to the /db/questions/ with no query parameters, return 303 with  **Location: /db/questions/?query-parameters-to-retrieve-the-default-page**.  Then provide a different URL by which whomever is consuming your API to get statistics about the collection (e.g., what query parameters to use if s/he wants the entire collection);

Answer (score 0):

While its possible to use the Range header for this purpose, I don't think that was the intent.  It seems to have been designed for handling flaky connections as well as limiting the data (so the client can request part of the request if something was missing or the size was too large to process).   You are hacking pagination into something that is likely used for other purposes at the communication layer.
The "proper" way to handle pagination is with the types you return.   Rather than returning questions object, you should be returning a new type instead.

So if questions is like this:

`<questions>
  <question index=1></question>
  <question index=2></question>
  ...
</questions>`

The new type could be something like this:

`<questionPage>
  <startIndex>50</startIndex>
  <returnedCount>10</returnedCount>
  <totalCount>1203</totalCount>
  <questions>
    <question index=50></question>
    <question index=51></question>
    ..
  </questions>
<questionPage>`

Of course you control your media types, so you can make your "pages" a format that suits your needs.  If you make is something generic, you can have a single parser on the client to handle paging the same for all types.  I think that is more in the spirit of the HTTP specification, rather than fudging the Range parameter for something else.