# Is it possible to get a part of page in an ajax get request?

Tags: ajax, http, jquery, get

I know we can fetch a whole page when doing a GET request to the server, but what if i'm only interested in one particular div on that page, or more exactly in its content. Is the only option here is to fetch the whole page, get the div content from it using jquery find() for example? Or is there some possibility to set up some kind of query to the server to ask for this particular div to return.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract part of HTML document in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137811/extract-part-of-html-document-in-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use a simpler form of jQuery's AJAX tool for this situation, `.load`.

```
$('#wrapper').load(href+fragmentSelector, function() {
    // callback to do stuff afterward
});
```

Here, we're loading content from the element with ID `fragmentSelector` from the url `href` into  `#wrapper` on our current page.

The entire page is still being requested, but only the content you request is returned.

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments

Answer (score 4):

```
$.ajax({
    'type': 'get'
    ...some params...
    success: function(response){
        $(response).find('div you are looking for').appendTo('div you want to append it');
    } 
});
```

For some params check [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

And answering your question: no, there is no way to get some parts of HTML without making special server-side service.

Comment: I understand this, but here as I stated before I download the whole page to the client, but i'd like to just download content that interests me to save bandwith, is that possible?

Comment: Yes, with backend (server-side) service that'll return only parts that you need. For a regular page - server will always answer with full page content

Comment: Yeah that's what i thought, my intention was not to use any server side code, just regular request for a part of page, but it isnt possible :\

Answer (score 1):

You can use [HTTP RANGE Header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html), but you can select a byte range to download and not a select content by DIV.

Example:

```
curl -r 0-1000 http://localhost -v
```

see [Using the HTTP Range Header with a range specifier other than bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434647/using-the-http-range-header-with-a-range-specifier-other-than-bytes)