# Can I use the HTTP range header to load partial files "on purpose"?

Tags: javascript, http, http-headers, range, filtering

I'm playing around with the HTTP range header ([specs](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.16)).

From what I understand I can set byte ranges of files ala

```
0-199/2000
200-499/2000
500-799/2000
etc
```

**Question:**
Say I only want to access certain ranges of a file, would it be possible to specify these ranges and then work with the "incomplete" data I received? I'm playing around with filtering a large log file, so I'm curious if something like this would work.

Thanks for inputs!

Comment: Seems to me like the perfect case to use that header. http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35.2

Comment: Yeah, I also think it was developed exactly for such cases. Haven't you tried if that works?

Comment: As has already been mentioned, that's *exactly* what range requests are for. This is generally how  media "streaming" is accomplished via HTTP.

Comment: yes. I'm thinking more into using this as a filter of a large file, similar to what is described [here](http://byterot.blogspot.fr/2012/07/range-header-asp-net-web-api-entity-pagination.html). Would be nice if it was possible to not only filter "from-to" like this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are right, the link which you posted in the comment would be probably the best approach. As your question sounded interesting i tried it out. You probably did it also, but here is an snippet *(for other, that may come looking)*

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","data.dat",false);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Range", "bytes=100-200");
xmlhttp.send();
console.info(xmlhttp); //--> returns only the partial content
// Tested on Win7 with chrome 46+
```

> **Watch-out:** the web-server **has to** support this Request Header **Range**, for it to work.

Comment: yeah. it's nice. I'm also playing around with it. Curious how to set custom-entities including related logic.

Comment: I assume Custom-entities would entail Serverside scripting/programming, and depence on webserver and programming language. here is a similar question/answer/approche/hint/... [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434647/using-the-http-range-header-with-a-range-specifier-other-than-bytes) :) .