# Download file in chunks in Chrome Javascript API?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Does the Chrome Javascript API support downloading a file in several chunks simultaneously? eg in a download manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no, no special support. There is a dedicated `chrome.downloads` API, but it's just the same mechanism as normal Chrome downloads, i.e. single stream.

Long answer: You can make it yourself via `XMLHttpRequest` by setting range attributes, e.g.

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Range", "bytes=100-200");
```

See more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200266/can-i-use-the-http-range-header-to-load-partial-files-on-purpose), and potential problems you can run into in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15561508/xmlhttprequest-206-partial-content).

Comment: If this gives me the error `Request header field Range is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.` can I get around that?

Comment: Just found out that's same origin policy. There goes my plans... thanks anyway.

Comment: @mm865 Do you have permissions for the site in question in the manifest?

Comment: Im just discovering all this documentation i havent seen. My extension will need to request from any site, so i will use `http://*/` and `https://*/`. I will set aboout readong the documentation first though.

Comment: @mm865 There is a `<all_urls>` match pattern that will do it. If you have a permission for a website, many origin permissions are bypassed with XHR.