# Download Files in chunk using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, html, chunks

I want to download large files in ( **GB**) using JavaScript or jquery library.

Anyone having idea about any **third party library which will  download files in chunk**.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23309841/download-file-in-chunks-in-chrome-javascript-api) you can use xhr and specify a range such as

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Range", "bytes=100-200");
```

you could then write a simple wrapper around it to download an entire file. There are probably also third party libraries which can help you, but I'm not familiar with any of those, and couldn't find any links for you in my immediate google searches.