# Get part of .txt file

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a big .txt file (~20MB) and i want to read just a few last characters of it, without downloading the whole file. Is there a way to do it with **javascript**?

File xxx.txt:

```
...soa9w78no18297f89v7e68941o29k8j86vh2b3iudo938v7h31byif0o10387vhibkiura
vo98e7shcbmukaog978hw83c7ozh98rh6ctbiuytc987sd6ergvnkq2r78hvksbytifuyno38^7vgwb3
                                                                          ^^^^^^
                                                                This part after ^
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200266/can-i-use-the-http-range-header-to-load-partial-files-on-purpose

Comment: @Quentin Great! Any example?

Comment: In the answer to that question