# Is it possible to read first line or n chacahters from json without download all data?

Tags: javascript, json

I have to take some information from a json file. The json file size is 450 KB. But i do not need all json file so i don't want to download json. The question is that is it possible to read n charachters or line by line from json file without download all file ? If it is possible how to do?

Comment: `Range` header perhaps; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200266/can-i-use-the-http-range-header-to-load-partial-files-on-purpose

Comment: When you create that json file give your specific name to file. Read fileName and decide read or not read.

Comment: And you want to do this clientside using XMLHttpRequest ?

Comment: yes client side @adeneo

Comment: If the server hosting the JSON allows it, a range header could be used, but I would probably use the webserver instead, where specifying the number of bytes to read is a lot easier, and then just do the ajax call to your own server.

Comment: @adeneo it is not my server.

Comment: @AlexK. i am trying to send range header request.

Comment: Also see: [How can I find out whether a server supports the Range header?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200266/can-i-use-the-http-range-header-to-load-partial-files-on-purpose)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the [HTTP Range header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233).

> This document defines HTTP/1.1 range requests, partial responses, and
> the multipart/byteranges media type.  Range requests are an OPTIONAL
> feature of HTTP, designed so that recipients not implementing this
> feature (or not supporting it for the target resource) can respond as
> if it is a normal GET request without impacting interoperability.
> Partial responses are indicated by a distinct status code to not be
> mistaken for full responses by caches that might not implement the
> feature.