# Correct handling of long-running HTTP processes

Tags: http, long-running-processes

I am building a REST-style Back End web service which serves up pre-generated blobs of data to a Front End site. The blobs themselves are not large and can easily be satisfied in a single HTTP response/request. The Back End is written in PHP.

It all works just fine. The difficulty is the blob regeneration, which needs considerably longer when there are many blobs. The regeneration can take longer than the response timeout on the (separately hosted) server.

I would like to proceed as follows:
– the initial request sent is "regenerate all blobs"
– processing starts, with no response until either all are complete (HTTP 200, all hunky-dory) or I reach an internal timelimit
– if the timelimit is reached, I want to send a response which indicates that the processing was incomplete (which HTTP status is appropriate, since the processing was successful, but incomplete? – 206 does not apply without Range headers...), so that the client can request continuation. I can imagine returning data that indicates what the "please continue" request should be (is this best done in a Link header?)
– the client then requests continuation and the loop continues until full success is signalled.

What is the best way to signal such things in an HTTP client-server exchange? I am prepared to write a short piece of Javascript to handle the client loop.

Thanks for any good ideas!

Answer (score 0):

I did quite a bit of research about Range headers, and came to the conclusion that there was not enough consensus about the effect of using a range unit that was not "bytes". Despite the fact that the HTTP statuses 200, 206 and 416 carry useful meanings. See http://otac0n.com/blog/2012/11/21/range-header-i-choose-you.html for a good summary.

So I ended up writing a special case solution with the result in each response signalling whether to rerun the query with a "resume" value that enables already-processed blobs to be skipped.

It would be just great if the Range stuff would also allow "items" as unit – this would enable simple collections to be handled via header parameters without additional overloading of the URI.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434647/using-the-http-range-header-with-a-range-specifier-other-than-bytes and floow links in the StackOverflow blogosphere