# When to respond with "accept-ranges" header?

Tags: rest, http-headers

[rfc2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.5) is pretty bare on the subject, and basically defines a header for people to use when they see fit.  The only obvious case I can see is a 416 response.  I'm new to rest and was just wondering whether there existed conventions on when to respond with this header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at least one example comes to my mind:

you can have `GET /book` method in your service

and you would like to add possibility to fetch only particular pages

instead of new method like `/bookpage` you can `accept-ranges: pages` and return only relevant page(s)

here is example of this http://byterot.blogspot.com/2012/07/range-header-asp-net-web-api-entity-pagination.html and http://otac0n.com/blog/2012/11/21/range-header-i-choose-you.html

also, this is discussed here [Paging in a Rest Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924472/paging-in-a-rest-collection)

Comment: Yeah I'm planning on using it for a similar case to paging, but was thinking it'd be more useful for this header to be returned via a HEAD request.  Seems kind of weird to send it in a GET considering they're already either retrieving the whole or part of a resource.  You're right though in that a 200/206 responses seem to have reached a point of convention from the resources floating around the net.  Hopefully you don't mind me waiting on selecting an answer for a day or two.  I do appreciate your input.